# Integrate two docker apps - Orthanc and OVIYAM

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to start two docker services. One is Orthanc and other is OVIYAM image viewer. My objective is to be able to view the images that I uploaded in Orthanc in Oviyam.

Step 1 - Upload images in Orthanc

Step 2 - View them in Oviyam

Though am currently able to start these two services, I am not able to integrate these two. I mean I did provide the listening port for OVIYAM which is 1025 in Orthanc.json.

**To start Orthanc**, I execute the below command

```
docker run -p 4242:4242 -p 8042:8042 --rm --name orthanc -v /home/test/abcd/abc/new_orthanc/orthanc.json:/etc/orthanc/orthanc.json -v /home/test/abcd/abc/new_orthanc/orthanc-db:/var/lib/orthanc/db jodogne/orthanc-plugins /etc/orthanc --verbose
```

**To start Oviyam**, I execute the below command

```
docker run -it --rm --name oviyam -p 8081:8080 -p 1025:1025 -v /home/test/abcd/abc/oviyam/data/:/usr/local/tomcat/work oviyam:2.7.1
```

I got the docker files for OVIYAM from this link (https://github.com/mocsharp/oviyam-docker) if that can help.

Though I am able to launch these services successfully, am not sure how I can integrate these two?

Am not sure how to setup this connection/integrate these two apps. Can you please help?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"?  Do you have any of your own source code that's relevant to this, or are you just trying to run two prebuilt Docker images?

Comment: By integrate, I mean to say, I want these two apps to interact with each other. I mean images uploaded in Orthanc should be viewable in OVIYAM. Oviyam has an option to configure the server details which I did for ORTHANC but still I am not able to get these two to interact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how those application communicate. If they talk to each other through network requests, you could use something like Docker Compose to start and link them together (https://docs.docker.com/compose/ , https://dev.to/mozartted/docker-networking--how-to-connect-multiple-containers-7fl).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the links.READ THEM. The issue right now is not with respect to starting this containers but how do I make these two interact with each other. I can use docker-compose to start them together but quite stuck in figuring out how to make them communicate with each other?

Comment: @AVLES you can use `links` (the old way) in docker-compose to link containers together (in terms of networking) https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links
Keep in mind that this might be deprecated by Docker in the future and the nice way of doing things is with network types: https://medium.com/@caysever/docker-compose-network-b86e424fad82
By default, Docker Compose assigns a network to each docker-compose 'stack' and you can communicate between services via an internal DNS.

Say you have two containers `svc1`, `svc2`. You will access `svc1` from `svc2` via this url `svc1:port`